# </hr>/input>>\ is a part saying that it is 'Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for 'input.' How to I change it so it is correct?

Tags: javascript, html, jsx

```
<form>
<div class="control input-field">
<input id="timer-input" type="number">
<label for="timer-input">Hours</label> />\
</hr>/input>>\
<hr>\
<label for="time_picker">This is time picker:</label>\
<input type="time" id="time_picker" />\
</hr>\
</div>
```

The part where it says /input>>\ is the part I have a problem on.

Comment: What is this on **line 5** `</hr>/input>>`

Comment: What do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: `/>` is the correct way to close what are known as "Self-Closing Tags" such as `<hr/>` => `<br/>` => `<img src=""/>` => `<input type=""/>` Maybe this list might be of some help [**W3 Void-Elements**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#void-elements)

Comment: Even with just the basic SO syntax highlighting you can see where the problems are so I'm guessing you're working with a text editor without syntax highlighting. Check out Sublime or Visual Studio Code.

Comment: The tag closing are not proper. and <hr> does not need closing i supppose.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned it up

```html
<form>
<div class="control input-field">
<input id="timer-input" type="number">
<label for="timer-input">Hours</label>
</hr>
<hr>
<label for="time_picker">This is time picker:</label>
<input type="time" id="time_picker" />
</hr>
</div>
```

Not sure what the other stuff was. Hope this helps.